# Multivariate normal distribution independet iff uncorrelated

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I found a few threads about this but none of them answered my question.

I am supposed to show that if you have random variables $X_1$,$X_2$ that are gaussian distributed and they fulfill that $$E(X_1)E(X_2) =E(X_1 X_2)$$ which is our definition of being uncorrelated, then they are also independent.

Most answers use that in that case the matrix in a multivariate normal distribution has to be diagonal, but I don't see the relationship between $$E(X_1)E(X_2) =E(X_1 X_2)$$ and this diagonal fact?

By the way: I know that this would solve the problem, as in that case we would have that $f_{(X_1,X_2)} = f_{X_1}f_{X_2}$ which would mean that they are independent, but I still don't understand this first thing.

Comment: The covariance between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $Cov(X_1, X_2) = E(X_1X_2) - E(X_1)E(X_2)$, which is $0$ by your assumption. That means the vector $(X_1, X_2)$ is Gaussian with a diagonal covariance matrix. More specifically, $\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & 0\\0 & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix}$ is the covariance matrix of $(X_1, X_2)$ where $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$. You can then verify that $f_{(X_1, X_2)}$ is indeed equal to $f_{X_1} f_{X_2}$.

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know that the entries of this matrix are the covariances. Is there any reason why this must be the case?

Comment: I assumed that you are allowed to know what the *variance* of $(X_1, X_2)$ is since you mentioned $f_{(X_1, X_2)}$. I also assumed that you know what the multivariate Gaussian distribution is, so that you can write out its pdf given the mean and the variance (which is a matrix). I believe you might need to resort to something more complicated if you are not allowed to use these facts.

Answer (score 9):

If $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a joint Gaussian distribution such that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are uncorrelated, then their covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is diagonal. Then, expanding out the exponent $-(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$ noting $\Sigma$ is diagonal (and thus $\Sigma^{-1}$ is too) in the Gaussian distribution gives $\sum_i -(x_i - \mu_i)^2/\sigma_i^2$. Noting $e^{a+b} = e^a e^b$, we see that the joint distribution factors into a product of 1-d Gaussians with means $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$. Thus, uncorrelated and jointly Gaussian implies independent.

Reversing this proof gives independent Gaussian RV's form a joint Gaussian distribution which the different RV's are uncorrelated.

Note the definition of $X_i,X_j$ being uncorrelated is $E[(X_i - \mu_i) (X_j -\mu_j)]=0$. This is precisely the i,j-th element of the covariance matrix for $i \neq j$. For $i=j$, we simply get the variances on the diagonal).

Comment: My question was: Why does being uncorrelated mean that the covariance matrix is diagonal?

Comment: Its the definition of uncorrelated - two RV's are uncorrelated if their covariance is zero.

Comment: yes, but how do I come from zero covariance to: The covariance matrix is diagonal?

Comment: the thing is that we don't know that the elements of the covariance matrix are the expected values of the products. Is this obvious, why this must be the case?

Comment: Thats the definition of the covariance matrix.