# $\sum_{i=1}^n(Z_i - \bar{Z})^2$ and $\bar{Z}$ are independent.

Tags: probability

$Z_i \sim N(0,1)$ and iid. Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n(Z_i - \bar{Z})^2$ and $\bar{Z}$ are independent.

I know that $cov(Z_i - \bar{Z}, \bar{Z}) = 0$, and $Z_i - \bar{Z}$ and $\bar{Z}$ both have a normal distribution. I also know that if $Z_i - \bar{Z}$ and $\bar{Z}$ are independent, the function of these are also independent.

Our lecturer says that if two random variables have a normal distribution and the covariance of these are zero, then two random variables are independent of each other. But, I am wondering why is that.

Comment: If two random variables have a joint distribution that is bivariate normal and their correlation is zero, then they are independent (this is just the formula for the bivariate normal distribution).

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006297), [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803329), or a [post on the statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304838) (among many).