# Linear regression(Independence of random variables used in linear regression)

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence, linear-regression

Suppose Y=X$\beta$+$\epsilon$, where $\epsilon\sim N_{n}(0,\sigma^2I)$, is a linear model. Now, I am assuming that in the data point($x_{i},Y_{i})$, $x_{i}$ is some constant and not a random variable. $Y_{i}$ is the i-th element of the vector $Y$ and is a random variable.  It is easy to find the distribution of the vector $Y$ and $\hat{\beta}$, where $\hat{\beta}$ is the estimator vector of $\beta$. $\beta$ itself is not random but $\hat{\beta}$ is as it is an estimator. Also, I am letting $\hat{Y}=X\hat{\beta}$ i.e. $\hat{Y}$ is the predicted value of the vector $Y$ . I want to know the answers to the following questions:

i) Are $Y_{i}$ and $\hat{Y_{i}}$ independent random variables?

ii) Are $Y_{i}$ and $e_{i}$ independent random variables? Here $e_{i}=Y_{i}-\hat{Y_{i}}$.

iii) Are $\hat{Y_{i}}$ and $e_{i}$ independent random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (i): If $X=I$, then $\hat{Y} = \hat{\beta} = Y$.

Hint for (ii): Let $n=2$ and $X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $\hat{Y} = \begin{bmatrix}Y_1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so $e = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ Y_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

(iii):

I will assume $X$ has linearly independent columns so that $X^\top X$ is invertible.
Then $\hat{\beta}$ has the explicit formula $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y = \beta + (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top \epsilon$, and thus $$\hat{Y} = X\beta + X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top \epsilon$$ and $$e = (I-X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top) \epsilon.$$

$\hat{Y}$ and $e$ are jointly Gaussian (since they are linear transformations of a Gaussian vector $\epsilon$), so "$\hat{Y}$ and $e$ are independent" is equivalent to "$\text{Cov}(\hat{Y}, e) = 0$." (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803329/multivariate-normal-distribution-independet-iff-uncorrelated).)

For shorthand let $H=X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$ so that $\hat{Y} = X\beta + H\epsilon$ and $e=(I-H)\epsilon$.
We have
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(\hat{Y}, e)
&= \text{Cov}(X\beta + H\epsilon, (I-H)\epsilon)
\\
&= \text{Cov}(H\epsilon, (I-H)\epsilon)
\\
&= E[(H\epsilon - E[H\epsilon])((I-H)\epsilon - E[(I-H)\epsilon])^\top]
& \text{defn. of covariance}
\\
&= H E[(\epsilon - E[\epsilon])(\epsilon - E[\epsilon])^\top] (I-H)
\\
&= H (\sigma^2 I)(I-H).
\end{align}
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer. I understood it now.

Comment: Hi! I have a small doubt. H-H^2=0 so we get that Cov(Y-hat,e)=0 and so they are independent. I got this but there is another thought which is contradicting this fact. As ei=Yi-Yi(hat) so for a moment let us fix Yi. Now, we can alter the value of Yi(hat) by choosing a quadratic model or some other model. Choosing another model will change the value of Yi(hat) while keeping Yi fixed. This will change the value of ei so shouldn't ei and Yi(hat) be dependent?

Comment: @KaustavChoubey My answer is specifically in the case where $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y$ is the least squares estimator for your linear model. I'm not sure why you are considering other estimators/models.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I wanted to say that if I choose a linear model for example the null model or the quadratic regression ( Yi= β_0 + β1x + β2x^2+\epsilon)) for some data, then I am able to change the value of Yi-hat and hence the value of ei without changing Yi. The values of Yi-hat are affecting the values of ei so they should be dependent. I know I am making a mistake somewhere when I am making this argument because you have given a rigorous proof that they are independent but I don't know where I am making the mistake.

Comment: @KaustavChoubey You've written a quadratic model as $Y_i = \cdots$; doesn't this affect $Y_i$?

Comment: This is of course quadratic in x but it is linear in betas. So, it will be a linear model. Had there been some term like beta^2 or some other power then the model wouldn't have been linear. The formula  β^=(X^⊤ X)^−1 X^⊤ Y is applicable in this case as well. Well, your question 'doesn't this affect Yi' is the point where I am doing a mistake. I was considering that the data is already given so the values of Y1, Y2, Y3, ..., Yn are already given and then I was applying different linear models on this data. I guess considering that the data is given is the wrong point.

Comment: @KaustavChoubey "Considering that the data is given is the wrong point." Yes, the source of randomness is the $\epsilon$ in the model $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$ (else, it does not make sense to talk about independence), and the estimator $(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y$ must use the same $X$ from this model. You can consider using different estimators or different models, but that would be out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Hi! I have one more doubt. In i) You have considered that X=I. Then, Y-hat=Beta-hat(that's true) but how does that imply that Y-hat=Y?

Comment: @KaustavChoubey $\hat{Y} = X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top Y = Y$ when $X=I$.